# Can't make a network request in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, xmlhttprequest, fetch-api

I'm using a service to access user's geolocation. 
The problem is that the request works ONLY when I turn on the "Network inspection" mode in the react-native debugger.

Otherwise it fails with an error:

```
    TypeError: Network request failed
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onerror (whatwg-fetch.js:504)
    at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (event-target.js:172)
    at XMLHttpRequest.setReadyState (XMLHttpRequest.js:580)
    at XMLHttpRequest.__didCompleteResponse (XMLHttpRequest.js:394)
    at XMLHttpRequest.js:507
    at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit (EventEmitter.js:189)
    at MessageQueue.__callFunction (MessageQueue.js:366)
    at MessageQueue.js:106
    at MessageQueue.__guard (MessageQueue.js:314)
    at MessageQueue.callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue (MessageQueue.js:105)
```

For data fetching I'm using a regular fetch, but already tried XHR and axios with the same results.

```
export function getUserGeoLocation() {
    const url = 'https://geoip.tradesmarter.com/json';

    return fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
```

The same request works on a web platform that's using Angular with jsonp.

```
export function getUserGeoLocation() {
  const url = 'https://geoip.tradesmarter.com/json';
  const opt = {
    timeout: 1000,
  };

  const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    jsonp(url, opt, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err.message);
      } else {
        resolve(data);
      }
    })
  );
  return promise;
}
```

Has anyone ever encountered a problem like this one?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added network ie Internet permission for android and ios